# Retrieving Linkedin Group discussion posts

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am making an application in which i have to make connnect to linkedin and after connecting i've to retrieve group discussion posts and all other information that i can retrieve related to group
I dont know where to start :( 
I have APIkey and SecretKey
Can anyone provide the sample code

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I dont know where to start

The [documentation](http://developer.linkedin.com/apis) of the API you are trying to use is generally a good place to start.

Here's how I would proceed if I was at your place:

1. Head over to the [documentation](http://developer.linkedin.com/apis)
2. Read it carefully
3. Start designing a POC (proof-of-concept). Could be a simple console application in which you attempt to consume the API.
4. Once you have a working POC integrate it into your actual application

If in between those steps you encounter some specific problems you shouldn't hesitate to show your progress here and ask some real question instead of *give-me-the-code* type of questions.